# Changing activities using phonegap on android

Tags: android, cordova

How do you change activities using DroidGap? Is there  a way to get the current context even though we're using DroidGap?

```
public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (isOnline() == true) {
    super.loadUrl("http://myurl.com");
    }
    else {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(SOME CONTEXT...DroidGap.getContext(), LoadScreen.class);

        startActivity(myIntent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: You already written a solution. as a context you can use your current activity

Comment: @marwinXXII well my specific code of 'DroidGap.getContext()' returns an error saying that getContext is not a static method. How do I get the current context is my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved my problem `Intent myIntent = new Intent(getContext(), LoadScreen.class);`